# Java: Cannot get a digit zero to be equal to zero

Tags: java

I am creating a program that will determine and print the number of odd, even, and zero digits in an integer from the keyboard. I have tried a few different ways and have gotten the same result with each. I cannot get java to recognize 0 as 0, but only as an even number. Ex. 1005 will give 2 Odds and 2 Evens.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int zero = 0;
    int input;
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

System.out.println("Input an integer please: ");
input = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Your number is: " + input);

String x = Integer.toString(input);

for (input = 0; input < x.length(); input++){
    char a = x.charAt(input);        
  System.out.println(a);

  Character.getNumericValue(a);

  if (a==0){
    System.out.println ("+1 Zero");
    zero++;
}
else if (a%2 == 0 && a>1){
    System.out.println("+1 Even");
    even++;
}
else {
    System.out.println("+1 Odd");
    odd++;
}

}
System.out.println("There are " + odd + " odd numbers!");
System.out.println("There are " + even + " even numbers!");
System.out.println("There are " + zero + " zero numbers!");
}
```

Comment: first convert char a to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't assigned Character.getNumericValue(a) to int value .

```
  char a = x.charAt(input);        
  System.out.println(a);

 int y= Character.getNumericValue(a);

  if (y==0){
    System.out.println ("+1 Zero");
    zero++;
}
else if (y%2 == 0 && y>1){
    System.out.println("+1 Even");
    even++;
}
else {
    System.out.println("+1 Odd");
    odd++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [Character.getNumericValue(a);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) method returns an `int`. It does not implicitly change the parameter (the character variable 'a' in this case).

Thus, you should compare the return value of the getNumericValue method and not the original character.